# How to get width of a html element and convert from pixel to persentage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

How can I convert width of html element from pixel to percentage (relative to screen size)

For example get this element from DOM (where screen width is 1366px):

```
<div style="width:683px">hello</div>
```

And convert to this element (683px is 50% of 1366px):

```
<div style="width:50%">hello</div>
```

Comment: Why dont you just start with 50%?

Comment: Cos the element is generate by a pixel base library at runtime and I want to convert it to '%' units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the width of the element using a querySelector and then divide by the screen width:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.div');
div.style.width = `${(div.offsetWidth / screen.width) * 100}%`;
```

```css
.div{
background: black;
height: 60px;
width: 683px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the current window width and then divide it.

```
function getWidth(){
let width = window.innerWidth;
let half = width * 0.50;
}
```

And do with it whatever you need to.

Comment: Thanks but screen size and element width are totally dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

To get the width of the element

```
var divWidth = document.getElementById("mydiv").offsetWidth
```

Screen width is already in `screen.width`

To get the percentage value

```
percentDivWidth = divWidth * 100 / screen.width;
```

Then just replace the width

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.width = percentDivWidth + '%';
```

I haven't tried it but it should work, this doesn't depend on jQuery or other libraries.